Header based routing in ASP.NET Core Minimal API
I'm looking for a way to have multiple routes in my ASP.NET Core which differ by a certain header. I found this question which answers the same question BUT for a controllers-based API: Header based routing in ASP.NET Core
I'm looking for the same thing, but for a Minimal APIs. I found this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#route-constraints) describing custom route constraints, but I don't really care about any parameters (my path actually doesn't have any) so I don't know how to use it.

How many routes are we talking here? If it's just a handful then you're better-off having a single "normal" Action/Handler or Middleware func that inspects the request header and simply makes a direct method-call  - it really isn't worth the effort to get into the ductwork of ASP.NET's infra unless the effort-to-reward ratio is there (though if you're wanting to do it for learning reasons or for a challenge, that's different - I assume you're just wanting to do things properly but your boss/client would rather you shipped something sooner, even if internally it's not pretty to look at.

(I wryly note that "Minimal API" in ASP.NET Core started-off as an attempt to lower-the-barier-of-entry for ASP.NET to avoid overwhelming newcomers with the Startup ceremony - but now it's a meaningless buzzword because using "Minimal API" does nothing to help prevent projects of nontrivial complexity ending up as a hot mess after spending 5-6 years in prod, or worse: handing it off to a 1st-year intern)

You're right it's just a few routes and I already spent more time with it than is justifiable  but Im taking it as a learning opportunity

Following code works to map minimal endpoints conditionally.
app.UseRouting();
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Headers["route"]=="A", (appBuilder) =>
{
    appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("A", () => { return "A result"; });
    });
});


Looks promising, I'll try it out tonight, thx

Works like a charm :)
